# Why is ('.class', this) not working?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Both of these scripts are not working with JQuery Mobile

JS

```
$(this).find('.class').on("tap",function(){
  $( ".class-hidden" ).toggle( "slow" );
});


$('.class', this).on("tap",function(){
  $( ".class-hidden" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="class-hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any reason either of these functions would not work with the below text?

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: No that was just a typo on making the example. I'm searching for a bug in jquery mobile that would explain why this is not working. I strongly believe that this has something to to with jquery mobile since the event can be logged through non-jquery mobile actions.

Comment: Is the .class element present when the page loads or is it added dynamically?

Comment: It's loaded through dynamically through handle bars. The asp.net server page pulls in an xml feed and processes it into html.

Comment: I think the most important question is the first question in comments

Comment: `this` checks any element selected to see if it has the class '.class'

Comment: @JosephCasey the point of the `this` question is if code shown isn't wrapped in other code that provides context to `this`  then it is the `window` and `this` shouldn't be used

Comment: I thought $(this) as a selector was simply the DOM element invoked by an action, not always needing reference. Apparently I am wrong.

Comment: If you're trying to check `this` whether it has *it's own* `.class` and return a jQuery object, use `$.filter()`. But really, use the delegate selector in `$.on()`; that's what it's for.

Comment: @JaredFarrish  context argument of `$()` is same as using `find()` not `filter()`

Comment: @charlietfl - I know? That's not what I said. Edited comment to make that more explicit.

Comment: @JosephCasey You're partially correct in your `this` thinking. Inside of `.on()` callbacks, jQuery sets the `this` context as the raw DOM element that triggered the action. However, your use of `this` is *outside* of said callback functions, so it will be whatever the context is out there, which is probably not a DOM node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huangism is correct in that if `this` is not the correct context (an element that will be parent to the `.class` items) then that is a root problem.  In this case, you can try changing `this` to `document`, which is a bit heavy handed but will tell you if that is your problem.

Otherwise, since the items that you are attaching the tap event to are added dynamically, you would need to attach the event to their parent, `this`, and tell the event to fire when elements of class `class` are clicked.

```
$( this ).on( "tap", ".class", function() {
  $( ".class-hidden" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```